# How can I use relative paths when using the Window's "runas" command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, runas

I am trying to use the runas command in a folder system that I built to run multiple scripts as a different user. When I enter the entire file path of the script I want to run such as:

```
runas /user:jmc C:\foo\script.bat
```

It works fine, however, when I try to us a relational file path it fails saying that it could not find the script. So these commands cause it to fail.

```
cd C:\foo
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:jmc .\script.bat
```

Does anyone know how to use relational file paths in the runas command?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to `cd` INSIDE the runas environment. When you runas, the new shell is essentially completely disconnected from your original shell that ran the runas, and the new shell wills tart up in the new user's home directory, **NOT** the one you did the runas in.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 3):

as per http://tmdean.blogspot.com/2015/07/preserving-current-working-directory.html you can do this:

```
runas /netonly /u:domain\user "cmd /c \"cd \"%CD%\" ^& program"
```

Answer (score 0):

This post it is a bit outdated, but now you can use the option "env" to attach the environment of the launched program to the current execution env:

```
cd C:\foo
runas /env /user:jmc .\script.bat
```

Comment: That depends on windows version I would guess?

Comment: well, five years ago windows 10 was already out

Answer (score 0):

I think more correct version of [avs099's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811804/5197544) should have additional `\\` after `%CD%` to work properly  and `/D` flag after `cmd` to able change current disk as well. So, corrected version looks like:

```
runas /netonly /u:domain\user "cmd /c \"cd /d \"%CD%\\\" ^& program"
```

Actually, I use and checked it with other parameters:

```
runas /savecred /user:someuser "cmd /c \"cd /d \"%CD%\\\" ^& \"any\path\program.exe\""
```

Both `/netonly` and `/savecred` aren't related to the questions.